# Get width and heigh from an input file

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have to get the width and height of an imagen I selected from an input file. I've tried using this, but is not working.

HTML

```
<form id="formimg">
    <label>Selecciona una imagen</label>
    <input type="file" name="txtFile" id="txtFile" accept="image/*">
</form>
```

JS

```
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    $("#txtFile").change(function(e) {

        var image, file;

        if ((file = this.files[0])) {
            image = new Image();

            image.onload = function() {
                alert("La imagen es de ancho " + this.width + " y largo " + this.height);
            };

            image.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
        }


    });
```

Comment: i tried it and its working in chorme browser. in which browser u r testing ?

Comment: i tried in chrome too

Comment: there is a way to make it work in previous versions?

Answer (score 0):

If your JS is declared in the `head` section of your HTML you will not be able to access any elements in the document as HTML is interpreted from top to bottom. You can overcome this by using `$(document).ready`.

```
        var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#txtFile").change(function (e) {
                var image, file;

                if ((file = this.files[0])) {
                    image = new Image();

                    image.onload = function () {
                        alert("La imagen es de ancho " + this.width + " y largo " + this.height);
                    };

                    image.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
                }
            });
        });
```

Alternatively you can try attaching the event handler to the field using the `onchange` attribute by defining a function:

```
        var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        var changeHandler = function (e) {
            var image, file;

            if ((file = e.files[0])) {
                image = new Image();

                image.onload = function () {
                    alert("La imagen es de ancho " + this.width + " y largo " + this.height);
                };

                image.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
            }
        }
```

and your form:

```
    <form id="formimg">
        <label>Selecciona una imagen</label>
        <input type="file" name="txtFile" id="txtFile" accept="image/*" onchange="changeHandler(this)">
    </form>
```

Comment: Don't forget, the js doesn't run until `$("#txtFile").change`, so i don't think it would matter if the js is in the head in this case. It would be worth checking that it comes after jquery though. Should ask this in the question's comments.